# Converting key to binary for encryption

Tags: php, encryption

I see in a lot of PHP example code for encrypting were the key is converted to Hex using pack().

```
$binaryKey = pack('H*', $key)
```

I created a two methods using the mcrypt function to encrypt and decrypt without converting the string key and it tests out with no problems.
Am I missing something by not converting the key to Hex?

Comment: In that case you're using a different key then. Your key has the size n*2 and the alphabet consists of 16 symbols while the "pack-version" uses a key of size n and its alphabet has 256 symbols per character.

Answer (score 1):

The key is converted *from* hex to binary using the `pack` method.If you don't do this then your key contains half as much entropy (randomness) per byte. For instance an 128 bit key would be stretched to a 256 bit key with 128 bits of entropy. AES-128 would become AES-256, so a slightly different algorithm would be used.

PHP's mcrypt makes detecting this kind of thing rather tricky as it will accept any size key. It will just add zero's until it finds a key length it can use, and if it is over 256 bit (for AES) then it will remove any byte after the first 32. This is considered (extremely) bad practice by cryptographers. So in your case a 256 bit key may be stretched to 512 bit, only to be cut to 256 bits afterwards. Your key will only contain the lower 128 bits of the 256 bits key, in hex!

So if you have a nice 192 or 256 bit key, yes, you will miss some key information. Furthermore, you could run into compatibility issues and very angry colleagues later on.